# php if else statement time schedule

Tags: php, date, schedule

I'm using PHP to schedule images to come up on a website at a specific time. I'm fine until a picture has to come up say at 9:42am and end at 10:42am. a can get top of hours and partial hours ending at top of hour but I can't figure out how to schedule multiple partial hours in a row. This is what I'm using

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$h = date('G');
$m = date('i'); 
$d = date('w');
$year = date('Y');

// MONDAY SCHEDULE
if ($d == 1 && $h >= 0 && $h < 1) { $img = 'opendoor.jpg'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 13 && $h < 14) { $img = 'newtime.jpg'; } 
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 14 && $h < 15) { $img = 'weekend'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 15 && $h < 16) { $img = 'today.jpg'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 16 && $h <= 17 && $m >= 0 && $m < 30) { $img = 'walk.jpg'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 17 && $h < 19 && $m > 30) { $img = 'new.jpg'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 19 && $h < 20 && $m < 30) { $img = 'default.jpg'; }
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 19 && $h < 20 && $m > 30) { $img = 'test.jpg'; }
```

I followed a very good example given to me for my question, but for no apparent reason, some of the hours work and some doesn't. When I echo $img on one hour the code is printed but on the hour before or after it is ommitted. Here is a partial code of what I'm now doing:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$h = date('G');
$m = date('i'); 
$d = date('w');
$hhmm = date('H') * 100 + date("i");

$img = key(array_filter(array(
'images/hosts/image1.jpg' => ($d == 0 && $h >= 0 && $h < 1),
'images/hosts/image2.jpg' => ($d == 0 && $hhmm >= 0100 && $hhmm <= 0542 ),
'images/hosts/image3.jpg' => ($d == 0 && $hhmm >= 0542 && $hhmm <= 0600),
'images/hosts/image4' => ($d == 0 && $hhmm >= 0600 && $hhmm < 0630),
'images/hosts/image5' => ($d == 0 && $hhmm >= 0630 && $hhmm < 0800),
'images/hosts/image5.jpg' => ($d == 6 && $h >= 8 && $h < 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare "partial hours", then it might be best to combine hours and minutes into one value. You can often get away with `hours*100+minutes`:

```
 $h = date('G');
 $m = date('i'); 
 $d = date('w');
 $hhmm = data("H") * 100 + date("i");
```

So `$hhmm` would be `1230` for 12:30am, or `1942` for 7:42pm. The numbers jump between 1759 and 1800, but that's not an issue since you only want to compare with <= and => within time ranges anyway.

Also I would totally rewrite the if/else chain into an array comparison:

```
$img = key(array_filter(array(
   'opendoor.jpg' => ($d == 1 && $h >= 0 && $h < 1),
   'newtime.jpg' => ($d == 1 && $h >= 13 && $h < 14),
      ...
   'partialhours.jpg' => ($hhmm => 2142  &&  $hhmm <= 2242),
)));
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to give it a try. Is data("H") supose to be date("H") with an e or an a?

Comment: I created a schedule and for some reason some hours work and some hours don't, I can't find any particular reason but when I reset my clock for example 8:00PM works but 9:00PM and 7:00PM doesn't, here is a partial code of what I'm doing:

Comment: You've run across one of the odd PHP features called **[octal values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)**. When specifying the times, **don't write any leading zeros**. That will make PHP interpret `0600` as octal, it converts it into the decimal `384` prior comparison - which is why it leads to wrong results.  (However you can also test with `print_r()` in place of `key(array_filter(` while you debug the conditions. That will print out which entry actually matched.)

Answer (score 0):

please use `switch`

```
switch ($d)
{
  case 1:
    switch ($h)
    {
      case 1:  $img = 'opendoor.jpg'; break;
      case 13: $img = 'newtime.jpg';  break;
      case 14: $img = 'weekend.jpg';  break;
      case 15: $img = 'today.jpg';    break;
      case 16:
        if ($m<30) $img = 'walk.jpg';
        break;
      case 17:
        $img = ($m>30) ? 'new.jpg':'walk.jpg';
        break;
      case 18:
        if ($m>30) $img = 'new.jpg';
        break;
      case 19:
        $img = ($m>30) ? 'test.jpg':'default.jpg';
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand switch, i'm going to have to study it.